# Shared user table with Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, activeresource

I'm looking for a solution in order to reuse the **user** table of another web application that use Authlogic.

I'm trying with ActiveResource (in the new app), but I'm missing something. This is the not working code:

```
#Existing app
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :username, :email, :password
   acts_as_authentic
end

#New app
class User < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site="http://localhost:3001"
end
```

The real aim of this exercise is to build a webservice with only the Authlogic's user table. This web service should be used from many apps.

Anyone has any tip?

**EDIT**

Yep, sorry, this is the error in my view:

```
NoMethodError in Users#new
Showing app/views/users/_form.html.erb where line #5 raised:
undefined method `username' for #<User:0x103477bc0>
```

Comment: What isn't working about it? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Is a missing element_name declaration in the ActiveResource definition going to be a problem? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html

Comment: It shouldn't because I don't need self.element_name="user" as the model has the same name.

Answer (score 1):

```
undefined method `username' for #<User:0x103477bc0>
```

You cannot use the method new on ActiveResource resources. Or better, you can instantiate a new User with User.new but creates a local object without remote attributes.
Try with:

```
User.create :email => "mail@email.com", :password => "1234"
```

This create a remote user with these attributes.